# Django Model QuerySet: RuntimeError generator raised StopIteration

Tags: django, python-3.7

I've recently updated my Django to version 2.2.4 and python to 3.7,
and I encounter this error randomly:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/foo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 73, in __iter__
    obj = model_cls.from_db(db, init_list, row[model_fields_start:model_fields_end])
  File "/foo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 511, in from_db
    for f in cls._meta.concrete_fields
  File "/foo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 511, in <listcomp>
    for f in cls._meta.concrete_fields
StopIteration
```

I tried to debug the code to find out what's happening, and it seems the `from_db` function in `django.db.models.base.py` is causing this error:

```py
# /foo/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py
...
@classmethod
def from_db(cls, db, field_names, values):
    if len(values) != len(cls._meta.concrete_fields):
        values_iter = iter(values)
        values = [
            next(values_iter) if f.attname in field_names else DEFERRED
            for f in cls._meta.concrete_fields
        ]
    new = cls(*values)
    new._state.adding = False
    new._state.db = db
    return new
...
```

`next(values_iter)` is raising this error and it seems that Django devs should surround that with `try except` block to make this work in python 3.7,
but my question is, is there a way to overcome this issue as a temp fix or not?

thanks.

**Update#1:**

I've found out when exactly this error happens, When I call `.values_list('myfield', flat=True)` on a `QuerySet`, the query changes to `SELECT myfield from ...` and this breaks everything.

Comment: Show the full traceback, also the relevant parts of your code. There is nothing wrong with Django's code.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal, unfortunately, it's a very complex code which stores a `QuerySet` instance in a class attribute and passes it across multiple filter-classes which manipulate the query, I fixed my problem by encapsulating `values_list()` calls and store db entity ids in lists instead of `QuerySet`